# How to import a module hosted in a git repo in ANSIBLE?

Tags: git, deployment, ansible

I am working in a playbook which needs to install the C++ Boost library.

Fortunately, I have found a GitHub repo which contains a Boost library installation playbook.

How could I import that playbook? Is there any statement in Ansible to import a module hosted in GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-pull.html) it basically pulls and applies your playbook hosted in a git repository.

From the docs:

```
ansible-pull -U <repository> [options] [<playbook.yml>]
```

For testing, at the root of the repository you could have this playbook, named `/local.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name:  uname
      command: uname -a
      register: uname

    - name: debug uname
      debug:
        msg: "{{ uname.stdout }}"
```

Then you could call it using something like:

```
ansible-pull -U git@github.com:<user>/ansible.git local.yml
```

But in long-term, to avoid depending on the repository, you may want to clone the module/role and just adjust your playbooks.

Comment: > But in long-term, to avoid depending on the repository besides depending also on your environment, you may want to clone the module/role and just adjust your playbooks.

If I copy it to my playbook wouldn't I lose the capacity of update it in the future, when the maintainer update his module?

Comment: Can it be coded in the playbook instead of using it with a command in the command line?

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez check the [ansible-galaxy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/galaxy.html) command probably could give you some ideas